# Can "Es tut mir leid" be used to express empathy rather than remorse?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase, expression

I have been wondering, reading online and discussing with friends over this German expression for a long time. 
I want to know if German speakers, Austrian males especially, feel that by saying "Es tut mir leid" they are expressing guilt and apologizing for a mistake they made. Is that its only meaning? 
**Or can it also be used to express with empathy that you are sorry about something that is ABSOLUTELY not your fault?** (by that I mean the "I'm sorry" we use in English such as "I am sorry you had a bad day" or "I'm sorry for your loss").

I am wondering **if you feel** you could react to the following situations by saying "Es tut mir leid, dass..." to express empathy and feelings of understanding towards another person, who might feel sad, angry, frustrated etc...

- Someone's grandma dies, you go to visit the person --> "Es tut mir leid, dass du traurig bist" or "Es tut mir für dich und deine Familie leid"
- Your girlfriend is sad because she had a bad day --> "Es tut mir leid, dass du einen schlechten Tag gehabt hast."
- A friend is down because he was criticized at work and has just told you --> "Es tut mir leid, dass es passiert ist"
- Your sister lost her connecting flight and calls you to complain and express frustration --> "Es tut mir leid, was passiert ist"
- A friend did not pass the most important exam of his Bachelor's degree and now has to wait a year to take the same exam again --> "Es tut mir sehr leid, dass du Pech gehabt hast".

If these expressions are not appropriate and natural would you please let me know what kind of **expressions could be used in German to react to them with empathy and understanding**?

I want to be able to express feelings in German but I am seriously having a hard time finding the right way.

Comment: What's wrong with a lot of context? The same expression can be appropriate or inappropriate depening exactly on the specific context.

Comment: Male native German speaker here (Germany), I do agree that "tut mir leid" could be used for all of these examples but I myself would rarely if ever use it that way. I use "Es tut mir leid" whenever I want to apologize or want to express my sympathy whenever I (partly) caused the other person's trouble but did not act with bad intends (which would be close to the only time I'd literally apologize using "Entschuldigung"). So for me, "es tut mir leid" is quite occupied being an apology. In all examples (or any case where I didn't cause the trouble) I'd likely say "tut mir leid für dich".

Comment: Why do you believe that it depends on the sex of the speaker, why restrict it to male Germans or german speaking persons? Did you encounter similar constructs, where it depends on the sex of the speaker? Is this the case in your mothers language?

Comment: @200_success: Konntest Du die Frage zum Geschleczht für E.V. beantworten, dass Du das 'male' so sportlich rausgekürzt hast?

Comment: This article discusses the gender issue. https://www.focus.de/finanzen/karriere/management/kommunikation/tid-15498/management-kommunikationsfalle-es-tut-mir-leid_aid_435350.html

Comment: @E.V:: Wenn Dir das "male" wichtig ist musst Du 200_success's Änderung Deiner Frage rückgängig machen. Eine Frage sollte beantwortbar sein, auch wenn man die Kommentare nicht liest.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer:
**Yes**, just like the English *I'm sorry* you can use *es tut mir leid* both for apologizing for something that is your fault and for expressing empathy.

Long answer:
Everyone of your examples is a valid way to express empathy in such a case. There are, however, other possibilities that might - in some cases - be more idiomatically.
In general, when someone tells you about his or her mishap or tragedy, Germans will often react quite automatically with

> Oh, das tut mir leid.
>   (Oh, I'm sorry for that)

A variant of that would be

> Tut mir leid, das zu hören
>   (I'm sorry to hear that)

It *might* be a regional thing, but I would connect the latter wording to situations where someone is disappointed (like having been to cinema and the movie was bad or an expensive vacation was not nearly as good as expected or something similar).

For a fatality of a close relative the normal phrase would be

> Herzliches Beileid
>   (Sincere condolences)

If the other person is not - or at least not only - sad about what happened but also (partly) upset (which is possible in all above examples except the fatality), it is perfectly acceptable to not pity that person but rather join that person's anger by saying something like

> So ein Ärger!
>   So ein Mist!
>   Verdammt!

like you would say *damn!* or **sh*t!** in English - or, when someone else is to blame (e.g. in your 3rd example the criticism was unfair)

> So ein Mistkerl!
>   (Such a Son of a B*tch!)

Comment: I agree. I think that generally "Das tut mir leid" is much more common in the situations described by E.V. than "Es tut mir leid".

Comment: Wow, so the difference would be into "das" vs "es". 
I would have never thought that little change could make any difference

Answer (score 3):

**Part I:**

> I want to know if German speakers, Austrian males especially, feel that by saying "Es tut mir leid" they are expressing guilt and apologizing for a mistake they made.

Yes, the expression *es tut mir leid* is used by German speakers to apologize for having caused a misery. This is irrespective of the speaker's origin or gender.

> Example:
>   
>   „Du hast den Herd wieder angelassen.“ – „Oh, tut mir leid. Morgen denke ich dran.“

**Part II:**

> DOES IT ALWAYS HAS TO BE LIKE THAT? Or can it also be used to express with empathy that you are sorry about something that is ABSOLUTELY not your fault?

The expression *es tut mir leid* is also used by German speakers when they did not cause the misery themselves, but when they want to express empathy with the other person.

> Example:
>   
>   „Ich bin heute gestürzt.“ – „Oh, das tut mir leid. Hast du dich verletzt?“

It is also appropriate in all five example situations described in the question.

Comment: Fascinating that you should use a sentence with _das tut mir leid_ to show what _es tut mir leid_ (or just _tut mir leid_) is supposed to mean. _Es tut mir leid_ or _Tut mir leid_, at least in my variety (and I'm an Austrian male), is only used to apologize. (Except if you use it as _Es tut mir leid, dass..._)

Answer (score 0):

I'd never use "es tut mir leid" for something I didn't do. Sounds like a bad direct translation from English to me. Only exception would be mean / sarcastic remarks: "Wenn du das nicht kapierst, tut es mir echt leid für dich!"

I can see "das tut mir leid für dich", but it still doesn't sound natural to me.

For expressing emphasis, people could as well try to encourage the person and try to lift their spirits. Depending on the situation you could say:

- "Kopf hoch, nächstes mal klappt es bestimmt." (e.g., after a failed test)
- "Morgen wird's besser" / "Schlaf erst mal drüber. Morgen sieht die Welt ganz anders aus." (e.g., after a bad day)
- "Ist natürlich doof, dass der Chef dich kritisiert hat. Vielleicht kannst du morgen  noch mal mit ihm reden, oder sehen, dass du die Sachen, die er kritisiert hat, besser machst." (after the boss criticized someone; this shifts the focus from empathy to helping, and may or may not be right for everyone)

Comment: Thank you Robert! Wonderful answer! 

Could you maybe articulate a little bit on why you would never use "es tut mir leid" for something you didn't do? 
From what I understood it is not natural for you, but I was wondering if you think it is also wrong to use it because you would admit a mistaken without having commited any! PS: are you from Austria or Germany?

Comment: On Duden (2) it seems that you could use it to --> jemandes Mitgefühl erregen
https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/leidtun

Comment: @E.V. Wonderful answer? It is simply wrong. „Mir ist heute dies und das passiert.“ – „Oh, das tut mir leid!“ Such conversations are very typical and absolutely normal.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Maybe a regional or age difference? I've never heard "es tut mir leid" to express compassion but in poorly translated English movies.

Comment: Robert: Was Du persönlich nutzt, ist hier nicht Diskusssionsgegenstand, sondern was (meist aktueller) Sprachgebrauch in Deutschland ist.

Comment: @userunknown Na, dann mal an die Belege. Deine Meinung ist nicht besser als meine.

Comment: Bei Gutenberg DE werden 1000 Stellen (das Maximum der Suchergebnisse) angeführt, unter anderem von Goethe, Bechstein, Dostojewski, bei denen es in diesem Sinne benutzt wird. Es ist völlig alltäglich. Ich verstehe überhaupt nicht, wie man darauf kommt, dass einem nur das Selbstverschuldete leidtun könne.

Comment: Björn, I assume your a convinced prescriptivist. In my opinion (descriptivist right here!) saying his answer" is simply wrong" is simply wrong. 
Depending on the speaker a certain word can be perceived in ways that are not what we find on the dictionary.

Comment: I really like this answer because it is descriptive and not prescriptive. Even though Duden might include several usages of a word, what I am interested is how people actually use a phrase. It is common knowledge that with time and enough people involved languages evolve and change. If enough time and enough people stop using "es tut mir leid" for something they didn't do also Duden will update the meaning and delete that option because it does not describe the real usage of the phrase anymore.

Comment: Dictionaries are there to be descriptive, rather than tell us how we are allowed or not to use our native language.

Comment: @E.V. It seems that you really believe that Roberts opinion is that of the majority. It's really the other way round! Again: the usage of _tut mir leid_ to express empathy is absolutely normal and in no way regional or of a minor group of speakers. It occurs everywhere in literature (see, e.g., Gutenberg DE) and everyday language. Really!!!

Comment: I honestly do not know how to establish what the majority thinks. Majority in Austria? Majority in Germany? Most women? Most men?
It is also possible that in Germany in your area it is generally accepted and natural and that for Austria it is something male speakers would never use that way.

Comment: Regarding the gender difference I thought this article was thought-provoking. https://www.focus.de/finanzen/karriere/management/kommunikation/tid-15498/management-kommunikationsfalle-es-tut-mir-leid_aid_435350.html

Comment: The use of *tut mir leid* to express sympathy is so common that it is taught at the **A1 level**, e.g. [here](https://www.goethe.de/pro/relaunch/prf/materialien/A1_fit/fit1_uebungssatz_01.pdf), p. 35, *Seit zwei Tagen habe ich Bauchschmerzen. – Das tut mir aber Leid.*

Comment: At B1 level I also had several lessons on the usage of the conditionals in German, then only after living in Austria I realized no one even uses it when they speak, apart from "würde, wäre, hätte and gäbe". I would have liked to know back then.

Comment: As you yourself noted, dictionaries reflect when many people use a phrase in a certain way, not when a single person has a restricted usage. The opinion of single individuals is not interesting in the least. But as long as you don't know the habits of said user, you can't derive the meaning of even a part of the speakers, not even if it is the majority.

Comment: This is not a mere language thing. It is also a culture and gender thing. Expressing "es tut mir leid" can be interpreted to mean admission of guilt. And expressing empathy, feelings or anything remotely related to compassion can be seen as a sign of weakness. We all live in different environments and for some people (not individuals as communication is always between at least 2) it can very well still have these meanings. In that case they are right to interpret it this way because that is the common understanding of their environment (social bubble). As much as I would wish it otherwise.